# How to access chat history in Twilio chat

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio

I am following this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat to integrate simple chat into my ASP.NET Core application. I don't understand where are messages from chat stored. Are they stored on Twilio server or I should manually store messages on my backend?

I have found two repositories with relevant code:

1. https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-csharp - when I start chat with this project, clients are able to chat, but new client is not able to see old messages
2. https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/twiliochat-csharp  - this code can start, but it is not possible to send messages with error code
   `WebSocket connection to 'wss://tsock.twilio.com/v2/wsconnect?token=eyJj...' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chat history is maintained unless you delete it. You can view chat history by joining an existing Twilio Programmable Chat channel which was used before.

You can also view the Chat history using the respective API's.

[Read multiple Message resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources)